# React: Generate array of objects before render to avoid changing an uncontrolled input error

Tags: reactjs

I need to populate array of "productPrices" based on currencies and priceLists in initial state

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     currencies:["EUR","DKK"],
     priceLists:["basic","extended"],
     productPrices:[]
    }
    }
```

like following

```
this.state = {
 currencies:["EUR","DKK"],
 priceLists:["basic","extended"],
 productPrices:[{currency:"EUR",priceLists:"basic",productPrice:0},
                {currency:"DKK",priceLists:"basic",productPrice:0},
                {currency:"EUR",priceLists:"extended",productPrice:0},
                {currency:"DKK",priceLists:"extended",productPrice:0},
               ]
}
```

I populate "productPrices" via componentDidMount which leads to "changing an uncontrolled input of type integer to be controlled", because componentDidMount is called after initial render where object in array isn't defined yet. I guess componentWillMount should solve this case, but it's now legacy. How can it can be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume the `productPrice` is populated by an api call.
Inside the `render` function we can put a check to detect when the api call gets finished, your code will look something like this -:

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.setState({loading: true});
    apiCallFunction().then((response) => {
        // Your processing for the `productPrice` property
        this.setState({loading: false});
    });
}

render(){
    if(this.state.loading){
        return (<Spinner // css spinner/>)
    } else {
        return // your component that you currently have. 
    }
}
```

This will avoid the `changing an uncontrolled input of type integer to be controlled` error.